# How to build XSD file properly?

Tags: xml, xsd

I built an **XSD** file based on the **UML** and the **XML** code (link and code below) but I can't validate the XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<Library
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="lib.xsd" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >

<authors>
    <author id="author1" name="Einstein"/>
</authors> 
<publications>
    <Book year="1942" title="7 Kingdoms" author="Einstein"/>
    <Magazine year="2010" number="203" title="The News"/> 
    <Book year="1956" title="The Fall" author="author1"/>
</publications> 
</Library>
```

Here is the **XSD** file that I built from the **UML** and the **XML code**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsd:element name="library" type="Library">

<!-- Begin KEY -->
    <xsd:key name="Author">
        <xsd:selector xpath="./authors/Author"/>
        <xsd:field xpath="@id"/>
    </xsd:key>

    <xsd:key name="Magazine">
        <xsd:selector xpath="./publications/Magazine"/>
        <xsd:field xpath="@id"/>
    </xsd:key>

    <xsd:key name="Book">
        <xsd:selector xpath="./publications/Book"/>
        <xsd:field xpath="@id"/>
    </xsd:key>

    <xsd:key name="Publication">
        <xsd:selector xpath="./publications/Magazine | ./publications/Book"/>
        <xsd:field xpath="@id"/>
    </xsd:key>
    <!-- END KEY -->

    <!-- Begin KEYREF -->
    <xsd:keyref name="Book.author" refer="Author">
        <xsd:selector xpath="./publications/Book/author"/>
        <xsd:field xpath="@ref"/>
    </xsd:keyref>
    <!-- END KEYREF -->     

    </xsd:element>


    <xsd:complexType name="Author">
        <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="Publication">
        <xsd:attribute name="title" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="year" type="xsd:integer"/>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="Magazine">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="Publication">
                <xsd:attribute name="number" type="xsd:integer"/>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="Book">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="Publication"/>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="Library">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="book" type="Book" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xsd:element name="magazine" type="Magazine" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xsd:element name="author" type="Author" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

I have an issue when I am trying to validate the XML file because it doesn't find the declaration of element "Library".

I am not sure that the **keyref name="Book.author"** created is enough to established the link between **Book and Author** and I believe the issue comes from this.

Do I need to add code in **complexType name="Book"** to create link and therefore, validate the XML file?

Comment: Don't know enough to comment, but is it case-sensitive?

Comment: @CecilWard Yes, case does matter.  Library vs library are two different things

Comment: It's a long time since I did (a lot of) XSLT etc, so am very rusty.

Answer (score 0):

Your schema does not match the XML at all

Currently the XML that your schema would represent is.

```
<library>
  <book title="title_0" year="100" /> 
  <magazine title="title_0" year="100" number="100" /> 
  <author id="id_0" name="name_1" /> 
</library>
```

Reasons why it won't validate against the XML

1. As CecilWard noted, your schema defines library with a lower case, but your XML sample has it as title case (Library).
2. Also your author node is not defined as being a repeating item under a authors node.
3. You have not defined a choice node that can either contain a book or magazine.  The unbounded should be on that rather that the book or magazine if they are intermixed like your example XML.

I just generated a schema of your XML and this will validate against that XML file.

It does not have any of the keyref's you defined, but you can add those back in.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Library">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="authors">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="author">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                  <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="publications">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="Book">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="year" type="xs:integer" use="required" />
                    <xs:attribute name="title" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                    <xs:attribute name="author" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Magazine">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="year" type="xs:integer" use="required" />
                    <xs:attribute name="number" type="xs:integer" use="required" />
                    <xs:attribute name="title" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:choice>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: In some situations I stick to all-lower-case identifiers.

Comment: @CecilWard  That is fine to do, but then both the XML and the XSD have to match.  In the OP case they didn't, hence the error the OP is getting.

Comment: sorry, unclear - I meant that I would stick to lower-case so as to avoid the possibility of case-sensitive mismatches. quite correct